# If statement doesn't seem to work in my jQuery code, althought it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function that does that a div-box called Karusell is being moved x px to the side by clicking on a different div-box called bokse1. The change is also animated. I also have a function that does that every time I click on bokse1 "1" is being added to "nextClicked". I tried to make it so that when nextClicked = 2 the first function will stop working by doing if (nextClicked != 2), but it doesn't work for some strange reason.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbLjcpx1/7/

**Code:**

```js
currentNextClicked = 0;

nextClicked = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

  if (nextClicked != 2) {

    $("#bokse1").click(function() {
      $("#Karusell").animate({
        marginLeft: ["+=10px", "linear"],
      }, 400, function() {});
    });

    $('#bokse1').live('click', function() {
      currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
      nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
      console.log(nextClicked)
    });

  }
});
```

```css
#bokse1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#bokse2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#Karusell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: indigo;
  display: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bokse1"></div>
<div id="bokse2"></div>

<div id="Karusell">
```

Comment: once you bind an event to an element, in order to reset it you need to `.unbind()` it

Comment: How do I do that tho I don't understand? I'm new to coding.

Comment: @Krøsh your if condition should be inside handler and not outside

Comment: @Rajesh wow that was an easy fix, althought I dont understand why I cant have one if statement for every function, because now I need to put the if statement under both of the function. All in all, thank you!

Comment: as you seems to be beginnner, a little thing that can help you is the debugger view, you can do: debugger; on any line of your js to stop the process of your code and to do it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

The listenner on the bokse1 wont stop with your if,

to prevent the code to happen place your if after its clicked like:

```
$("#bokse1").click(function() {
 if (nextClicked != 2) {
  $("#Karusell").animate({
    marginLeft: ["+=10px", "linear"],
  }, 400, function() {});
 }
});
```

Because when you click JS goes directly inside your listener, the beginning of the code is called only once when you load the page

Comment: If I may ask, why there is a need for callback function in `animate`?

Comment: i think their is no need to do it, as its his code i didn't change it. Maybe he plans to do stuff in there when the animation is done

Comment: @YashKaranke duude, I know I need to have a callback because without it the animation won't happen, but I don't know why it won't happen without it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, your `if` condition is in `$(document).ready`. So when this callback will be called, then your `if` will be evaluated. However, it will not be called for every click.

On click only following code will be evaluated which does not have any condition.

```js
$("#bokse1").click(function() {
  $("#Karusell").animate({
    marginLeft: ["+=10px", "linear"],
  }, 400, function() {});
});

$('#bokse1').live('click', function() {
  currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
  nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
  console.log(nextClicked)
});
```

---

Also, in my understanding, you do not need 2 handlers. It can be handled in 1 as well

```js
$("#bokse1").click(function() {
  if (currentNextClicked++ < 2) {
    $("#Karusell").animate({
      marginLeft: ["+=10px", "linear"],
    }, 400, function() {});
  }
  console.log(currentNextClicked)
});
```

---

Also per the code shared, following code doesn't makes sense:

```js
$('#bokse1').live('click', function() {
  currentNextClicked = nextClicked;
  nextClicked = currentNextClicked + 1;
  console.log(nextClicked)
});
```

You have numeric values stored in 2 variables. If I have to guess, `currentNextClicked`  refers to current iteration and `nextClicked` points to next. But this can be achieved with one variable as well, as `nextClicked` will always be `currentNextClicked  + 1`. Also if you notice, `if` in above code is `< 2`. That is because, `!= 2` will be valid if `nextClicked` becomes more than 2. Using less than operator would be a better option if you wish to restrict it to 2 values only.

#### Suggestions:

- `$().live` has been deprecated. So you will not be able to upgrade easily. So as a suggestion, try to avoid it.
- Declaring a variable without `var|const|let` makes it global variable. Its a bad practice to bleed variables to global scope. So, always use a keyword to declare variable.
- Declaring a variable outside any function will also make it global. So try to even avoid that. Ideally, a variable should have restricted and very specific scope. That means, declaring a variable only in area it will be used.
- `!=` will perform a loose check. That means `2 != '2'` will return false but it should return true. Try using `!==` to enforce that passed variable is a number only.

**Sample code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentNextClicked = 0;
  $("#bokse1").on('click', function() {
    if (currentNextClicked++ < 2) {
      $("#Karusell").animate({
        marginLeft: ["+=10px", "linear"],
      }, 400, function() {});
    }
    console.log(currentNextClicked)
  });
});
```

```css
#bokse1 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#bokse2 {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

#Karusell {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: indigo;
  display: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bokse1"></div>
<div id="bokse2"></div>

<div id="Karusell">
```

---

#### Reference:

- [I've Heard Global Variables Are Bad, What Alternative Solution Should I Use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613310/ive-heard-global-variables-are-bad-what-alternative-solution-should-i-use)
- [What is the difference between the bind and live methods in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937039/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bind-and-live-methods-in-jquery)
- [Alternative to jquery live that can work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205769/alternative-to-jquery-live-that-can-work)